# How to replace string in form A_B to string in form B_A?

Tags: php, string, reverse

I have a string in form:

```
hello_world
```

Need to have a string in form:

```
world_hello
```

I know that I probably need to use `str_replace` function, but how to use it exactly? Or maybe there is a better method?

Comment: Simple question: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Sorry, but no. I need it only for two words and for _.

Comment: Near duplicate: [Change format of an array of names from "last, first" to "first last"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54580614/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `preg_replace`:

```
$input = "hello_world";
$output = preg_replace("/^(.*?)_(.*)$/", "$2_$1", $input);
echo $output;
```

This approach captures the terms before and after the underscore in two separate groups, and then builds the output by reversing their order.  This prints:

```
world_hello
```

Here is another approach using `explode` to generate an array containing both parts of the input:

```
$input = "hello_world";
$parts = explode("_", $input);
$output = $parts[1] . "_" . $parts[0];
echo $output;
```

Comment: This approach uses standard-techniques _regex-capturing_, _string-splitting_, _array-concatenation_ which are applicable in most programming languages. So it teaches basic tooling.

Comment: Some limitation must be noted: Does work __only for 2 words__. For reuse with more words like `hello!_world_x_y` it would fail on reversing all parts (output: `world_x_y_hello!`).

Comment: Thank you, that's great.

Answer (score 2):

If you searched here for `string swap` you would have found the answer 
[swap two words in a string php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41805925/5730279):

```php
// given a string with words concatenated by "_" 
$a = "hello_world";

// chaining: explode + reverse + implode
// using "_" as delimiter to split words by
$reversed_a = implode('_', array_reverse(explode('_', $a)));

// gives swapped words: "world_hello"
var_dump($reversed_a);
```

Try this in [Online PHP editor](https://3v4l.org/QOiuo).

#### Generic solution for reuse

Does not use specific words to search for, nor is it limited to a number of words. **Single parameter** used is the delimiter `_` to *detect word boundaries*. So it will reverse any number of words glued together with a specific char.

#### PHP documentation

Used functions:

- [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode): Split a string by a delimiter-string and return as array
- [array-reverse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reverse.php): Return an array with elements in reverse order
- [implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode): Join array elements with a glue string

Comment: `But memory-consumption is rather high` bollocks. You expect php to use 12mb of RAM for couple of arrays of such small strings lol? This is php's overhead. You can just `echo 1` and you will get almost same footprint.

Comment: @emix Thanks! I didn't know PHP's footprint portion :-) So I removed my judgment but left array-usage. In case anyone would like to reverse large texts using space as delimiter ;-)

Comment: You should drop the „performance” part completely imho. “Longer input strings” as in reverse the Bible? Isn’t it obvious if you put 1mb into the RAM the footprint will be 1mb larger?

Comment: @emix  Agree: here _performance is practically irrelevant_. Now I'm happy with my 1st PHP-answer (tbh: never coded PHP, but can't resist to answer).